# discord.py rewrite - checking if the bot has a certain permission through @command.before_invoke decorator

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

Discord.py Rewrite

In my snippet of code, I am trying to run a simple check command before it runs the actual command in discord:

```py
@command.before_invoke
async def check_perms(self, ctx): # being defined in a class
    # if 'administrator' in bot.permissions <<< My goal
        # pass and let the following command run
    # else:
        # Make the bot say it can't run an admin only action and raise a custom exception
```

How do I detect if the bot itself has the admin permission before it runs the command? I do not want to put try/except blocks in every command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`bot_has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.bot_has_permissions):

```
from discord.ext.commands import bot_has_permissions, Bot, BotMissingPermissions

class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

bot = Bot('!')

@bot.command()
@bot_has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def example(ctx):
    ...

@example.error
async def error_handler(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, BotMissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"I need the permissions: {' '.join(error.missing_perms)}")
        raise CustomException() from error
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: I would like the bot to respond if it doesn't have admin. In this case, It can't respond unless it does. I do want a try/except in this command though.

Comment: You can write an error handler that checks for the error the check raises. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: My goal in the post is to do a conditional statement that runs `if 'admin' in bot.permissions`. In my case, I cannot use try/except blocks. I meant if/else in my previous comment.